# #1064 - check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY word.pl ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql

My query:

```
SELECT id, pl, ka, user, users.imie, users.id, users.nazwisko, users.klasa 
FROM word 
LEFT JOIN users ON word.user = users.id BY word.pl ASC
```

It gives me this error:

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
   'BY word.pl ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `Order` in `Order By`

ALSO Both tables have an `id` column, so you need to call either/both `users.id` and `word.id` to avoid the ambiguous error:

```
SELECT users.id, word.id, pl, ka, user, users.imie, users.id, users.nazwisko, users.klasa 
FROM word 
LEFT JOIN users ON word.user = users.id 
ORDER BY word.pl ASC
```

Comment: @Progo: when people help you here, the answers should be considered to be clues that will help you on your way, not things that can be typed in verbatim. Tim's fixed one problem for you, can you fix the other? If you search for your new error message, you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: 1 point.  new user.  Point them to the help, teach them to know how to write a good question.  tolerance must be given for the young users to the site. if he had 1000 points or had asked hundreds of questions already, frustration makes sense, but not on those new users.  @progo: review http://stackoverflow.com/tour for how to use the site and expectations of those asking questions, and those answering them.

Comment: I think it was a valid question... Harshly worded perhaps, but valid none-the-less. Been a long day lol...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot ORDER:

```
ORDER BY word.pl ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Order by clause

```
SELECT id, pl, ka, user, users.imie, users.id, users.nazwisko, users.klasa 
FROM word 
LEFT JOIN users ON word.user = users.id 
ORDER BY word.pl ASC
```